# Editing variable / option within props from separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Within my `index.js` file I've setup `getStaticProps()` to fetch data from an exported function. My function takes 2 parameters, one for the type of listing and the quantity.

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const type = 0
  const data = await loadListings(type, 20)

  return { props: { data: data, type: type }}
}
```

The returned props are than accessed and passed to my `<Listings>` element.

```js
export default function Home(data) {
  return (
    <Page>
      <div>
        ...
        <Listings data={data.data}/>
      </div>
    </Page>
  )
}
```

I haven't been using NextJS for too long, so I am assuming I'm taking the wrong approach here in using staticProps. I'm wondering how I can edit the `type` variable from a different file causing the `loadListings()` function to be recalled and loading in new listings with the new returned data. For context I have a dropdown / filter component elsewhere.

Edit: Forgot to mention, attempting to call `loadListings()` outside of staticProps just triggers CORS as within my `loadListings()` function, I'm calling an API from another site.

Comment: Sounds more like something you should do client-side using an effect hook with a dependency on the `type`

Answer (score 0):

To refetch data when using `getStaticProps` use Incremental Static Regeneration check out on demand [On Demand](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation)